# findOneAndUpdate nested object in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Trying to use `findOneAndUpdate()` to change an object inside an array within MongoDB. The documentation for mongoDB's nodeJS driver isn't clear to me.
The document looks like this:

```
{
  _id:ObjectID(),
  some: string,
  body: string,
  steps:[
   [0]{name: "foo", state:"Q"},
   [1]{name: "bar", state:"Q"},
   [n]{name: "fooBar", state:"Q"}
 ]
}
```

I need to lookup the steps name (foo) and set it's state to P (for in progress) and then to C (for complete) when the task has been executed or E when it errors.

I'll then need to also grab the name of the next step to.

Finding the document isn't hard as I will have the _id already, it's the update portion that's getting me.

EDIT:
This is what I've got so far

```
  async msg => {
    const _id = msg.content.toString();
    const id = new objectId(_id);
    logger.info(`${name} consumer - Recieved new task, fetching details`, {
      id
    });
    try {
      const jobDetails = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: id },
        {
          /**/
        }
      );
      await consumer.task(jobDetails);
    } catch (e) {}
  },
```

It's the framework for a rabbitMQ consumer

Comment: Show us the code you're working on

Comment: Added existing code, though it's incomplete. The area I need is in the /* */

Comment: So basically you did nothing in terms of writing the update query apart from stating that docs are not clear.  Sounds like "write it for me" question.  Take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/ it has some almost copy-pasteable examples for your usecase.

Comment: No, I'd read that, but I if you don't understand the documentation, it's hard to apply it to your use case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know how would you choose wich letter to set - P, C or E, because it is not quite clear, but for replacing a value in mongoDB it would look like this (let's say for 'P'):

```
myCollection.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": docId, "steps.name": "foo"},
    {$set: {"steps.$.state": "P"}})
```

1. Find the document you need to change.
2. Find the object
   inside the array `"steps.name": "foo"`. And you get the position of
   that object in array.
3. You're setting new value for the object's
   property ( `$` reflects the position).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I know when to set each state. P is set when the consumer receives the task, C when it completes the job and E when it errors (so in the catch(e){...} ).

Comment: thanks, dude! I was looking for a solution like this.