# How to elegantly PATCH changes into mongodb without path conflicts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I'm attempting to do a PATCH request to a MongoDB store, by [updating an element in an sub-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527121/findoneandupdate-nested-object-in-array). This is what the data looks like:

```js
const booksSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, trim: true },
    author: { type: String, trim: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
)
const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)

const librarySchema = mongoose.Schema(
  { books: [ Books.schema ] },
  { timestamps: true },
)
const Library = mongoose.model('Library', librarySchema)
```

And this is how I'm updating the data:

```js
  const library = await Library.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: libraryId, "books._id": bookId },
    { $set: { "books.$": bookBody } },
  )
```

And in the process, I've run into problems with the [automated timestamp update conflicting with the $set command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994447/mongodb-update-in-array-fails-updating-the-path-companies-updatedat-would-c):

```sh
Updating the path 'books.$.updatedAt' would create a conflict at 'books.$'
```

The best solution I've come across to make this type of update without removing the automated timestamp update is to [manually set each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389844/mongoerror-updating-the-path-publications-pub-updatedat-would-create-a-con), like this:

```js
  const library = await Library.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: libraryId, "book._id": bookId },
    {
      $set: {
        "book.$.name": bookBody.name,
        "book.$.author": bookBody.author,
      }
    },
  )
```

...but this solution is very verbosely.

**Is there a more elegant way to do this type of PATCH request, perhaps using some kinda of object destructuring, that doesn't require maintaining a mapping of each field?**

Comment: Have you tried this option of updating [Mongoose timestamp](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps).

Comment: Yes, that's the option that is causing the problem. The timestamp auto update conflicts with the explicit `$set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if your intention is to perform a PATCH operation the way it's described in HTTP protocol:

> The HTTP PATCH request method applies partial modifications to a
> resource.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH

You should go with the "verbose" solution in your case, because your alternative update `{ $set: { "books.$": bookBody } }` will delete any property missing in the update from the updated book. It's not how PATCH should work, it's how PUT is intended to work.

You can make your code a little less verbose by introducing a helper function performing something like this (example uses lodash):

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

_.mapValues(book, (value) => {
   _.mapKeys(value, (innerValue, innerKey) => (
     `book.$.${innerKey}`
   )
)
```

Comment: I suppose I was surprised that mongoose doesn't already have some baked in solution for this, since PATCH updates are such a common pattern... thanks!!